# how to make the columns of a table movable only in the output in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

Is it possible to make columns of a table movable in the output, without changing the order in the database. I just want to drag and move columns in the output. the database type is Microsoft access and the code is in vb.net.

Thank You

Comment: Order them they way you want in your select statement.  If TableX has Col1, Col2, Col3 you can do "SELECT Col2, Col3, Col1 FROM TableX".

Comment: i want to move columns in the output like drag and change columns, I dontwant to make any changes in the code